# How should I query time series by using tags in Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.0?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am reading through user guide of Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.0, and I have a question on querying using this version. I wonder if I can use tags on different time series to do querying? If I can query by using tags, how should I write my query statement?